# Is there an AngularJS' auto-generator?

Tags: angularjs, html, code-generation

Is there something like:

```
rails new AngularApp
```

So that It generates a template of directories and files with routes, config and views?

Comment: [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) seems to be a popular scaffolding tool. Still voting to close as off-topic though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Matti suggested, [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html) is one of the best Scaffolding tool for AngularJS. In your term, it the best auto-generator for AngularJS.

To Install Yeoman:
`$ npm install -g yo`

To generate code:
`$ yo angular` or simply `$ yo`

More details : [Click Here](http://yeoman.io/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate template for angular i.e angular 4 use angular cli
provide node is installed in your machine

> *npm install -g @angular/cli*

to create new app

> *ng new yourAppName*
>
> *cd yourAppName*
>
> *ng server*

hit the url localhost:4200